# Is WPF an ECMA standard library?

Tags: wpf, standards-compliance

Is WPF an ECMA standard library?
Or it is just a part of MS .net implementation?
Any references please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is not.

the C# and CLR is ECMA, but WPF is not.

In more detail, BCL is ECMA but FCL is not.

WPF & WinForms should be FCL.